# Как сделать приложение работающие с входящими и исходящими вызовами?

Tags: java, android

Надо создать приложение для Android, которое при входящем и исходящем вызове, и во время разговора, будет показывать кнопку. При нажатии на кнопку должен показываться номер телефона.
Кнопка должна появляться справа во время вызовов и разговора. Просто появляться. Как сделать, что бы она появлялась только во время вызова а не все время была? И как получить номер абонента, с которым установлено соединение? Объясните как это реализовать?

Сама кнопка, выводящая информацию при нажатии, уже есть. Надо только что б появлялась она в нужное время, и надо получиь номер звонящего человека (пока получается только свой номер получить)

```
telephonyManager.getLine1Number(); свой номер

intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER); вообще ничего, не null а пустота

intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER"); вылетает
```

Comment: У вас тут очень обширный вопрос. Что именно вызывает затруднения — как показать кнопку вообще, как её показать во время вызова или разговора, как получить номер абонента, с которым установлено соединение?

Comment: Спасибо вторые сутки не открываете сообщение прицепица можно и к столбу у вас в сообщениях тоже не все гладко может комуто надо взятку дать?

Comment: Тупо так поступать ,тоже мне интелектуалы, новичкам надо помогать . Ответ очень нужен был.